# Rsync mkdir permission denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rsync

I am trying to use "Rsync" to copy my spark directory to all the slave machines by this command:

```
rsync -avL --progress /path/to/spark-0.9.0-incubating ubuntu@<Public_ip_of_slave>:/usr/local`
```

I am following the instructions on this site:

http://docs.sigmoidanalytics.com/index.php/Setup_hadoop_2.0.0-cdh4.2.0_and_spark_0.9.0_on_ubuntu_aws_cluster"

but I am facing an error which is permission denied to make the folders in the destination.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you have wrong target syntax. it should be `user@host:/some/dir` (while `/some/dir` can be `~`, you should avoid using `~`)

Comment: I tried that too, but not working

Comment: Can you create target directory manually in shell, after ssh into remote server?

Comment: I think the problem is that I did not own the destination folder, root did. So I should use the chown command on the destination folder to make myself own it, not root, but how I do not know.

Comment: try to reproduce manually what rsync would do - that is, ssh into remote server, and `mkdir /path/to/spark-0.9.0-incubating`. then try to create files in that directory. if you can't, so can't rsync

Comment: I can ssh into remote sever and create file but how to work with rsync

Answer (score 2):

The `ubuntu` user (which you are using for `scp`) does not have the appropriate directory permissions on `/usr/local` at the remote server.

Misconfiguration can result in security issues so changing the directory permission of `/usr/local` is not recommended. If you wish to do so run:

```
ssh ubuntu@remote-server 'sudo chown root:ubuntu /usr/local'
```

where `remote-server` is the hostname or IP of the remote server and assuming that `ubuntu` is an administrator. You may also allow all others to write to the directory:

```
ssh ubuntu@remote-server 'sudo chmod o+w /usr/local'
```

but this is more dangerous than the previous option.

Alternatively, you may copy it into your home directory first then issue a `sudo` command to move the files into `/usr/local`:

```
rsync -avL --progress /path/to/spark-0.9.0-incubating ubuntu@remote-server:~
ssh ubuntu@remote-server 'sudo mv ~/spark-0.9.0-incubating /usr/local'
```

`~` will be expanded to the home directory of the user, which in this case is likely to be `/home/ubuntu/`.

Do remember to change the permissions of `/usr/local/spark-0.9.0-incubating` as appropriate to allow access to authorized users using the `chmod` command.